# Value not appending to global array

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to run a multithreaded email checker to see if the emails are office 365 valid.

Looking over and over my code, I cannot seem to find the reason it's not working correctly.

It should be appending the email to a GOOD or BAD list.

Instead, it's not appending anything!

This is my code:

```
...

currentDirectory = os.getcwd()  # set the current directory - /new/

# Locations
location_emails_goods = currentDirectory + '/contacts/goods/'
location_emails_bads = currentDirectory + '/contacts/bads/'
location_emails = currentDirectory + '/contacts/contacts.txt'

now = datetime.now()
todayString = now.strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S')

FILE_NAME_DATE_GOODS = None
FILE_NAME_DATE_BADS = None

ALL_EMAILS = get_contacts(location_emails)

url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/GetCredentialType'

# Get all emails
def get_contacts(filename):
emails = []
with open(filename, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as contacts_file:
    for a_contact in contacts_file:
        emails.append(a_contact.strip())
return emails

def saveLogs():
global GOOD_EMAILS_ARRAY, BAD_EMAILS_ARRAY, file_bads, file_goods, FILE_NAME_DATE_GOODS,    FILE_NAME_DATE_BADS

#print(GOOD_EMAILS_ARRAY)

for good in GOOD_EMAILS_ARRAY:
    file_goods.write(good + '\n')
file_goods.close()

for bad in BAD_EMAILS_ARRAY:
    file_bads.write(bad + '\n')
file_bads.close()


def newChecker(email):
global url, GOOD_EMAILS_ARRAY, BAD_EMAILS_ARRAY

s = req.session()
body = '{"Username":"%s"}' % email
request = req.post(url, data=body)
response = request.text
valid = re.search('"IfExistsResult":0,', response)
invalid = re.search('"IfExistsResult":1,', response)

if invalid:
    BAD_EMAILS_ARRAY.append(email)
if valid:
    GOOD_EMAILS_ARRAY.append(email)
else:
    if valid:
        GOOD_EMAILS_ARRAY.append(email)
    else:
        BAD_EMAILS_ARRAY.append(email)

# The follow is showing empty array eventhough I have defined GOOD_EMAILS_ARRAY globally so it should be updating
print(GOOD_EMAILS_ARRAY)


def mp_handler(p):
global ALL_EMAILS
p.map(newChecker, ALL_EMAILS)

if __name__ == '__main__':

# Foreach email, parse it into our checker
# Define a filename to save to
FILE_NAME_DATE_GOODS = '{}{}{}'.format(location_emails_goods, todayString, '.txt')
FILE_NAME_DATE_BADS = '{}{}{}'.format(location_emails_bads, todayString, '.txt')

file_bads = open(FILE_NAME_DATE_BADS, 'a')
file_goods = open(FILE_NAME_DATE_GOODS, 'a')

p = multiprocessing.Pool(500)

mp_handler(p)

saveLogs()

p.close()
```

As you can see, I am trying to append an email to either GOOD_EMAILS_ARRAY or BAD_EMAILS_ARRAY.
The BAD_EMAILS_ARRAY and GOOD_EMAILS_ARRAY are global variables but it for reason won't append to them.

I am running this through multiprocessing if you need to know.

Any ideas or errors looking in my code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "minimal" and "reproducible". Pls remove all the irrelevant code and make sure the rest is properly indented, so helpers have a chance to know what your code actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Processes do not share memory, the global variable with same name in two processes are two different object.

If you need share state between processes, see this:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: I am using Pools not Processes in my question

Comment: `A process pool object which controls a pool of worker processes to which jobs can be submitted.` You need set the sharing state manually.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it turns out that I just needed to use the Manager from multiprocessing:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool
```

then I could use a normal array through the manager such as:

```
# Set empty arrays using manager so we can carry it over
manager = Manager()
bad_list = manager.list()
good_list = manager.list()
```

This allowed me to then use my script like it was, just using these new arrays by Manager which works just how I wanted :)

```
...

FILE_NAME_DATE_GOODS = None
FILE_NAME_DATE_BADS = None

# Set empty arrays using manager so we can carry it over
manager = Manager()
bad_list = manager.list()
good_list = manager.list()

# Get all emails

def get_contacts(filename):
    emails = []
    with open(filename, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as contacts_file:
        for a_contact in contacts_file:
            emails.append(a_contact.strip())
    return emails

ALL_EMAILS = get_contacts(location_emails)

url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/GetCredentialType'

def saveLogs():
    global file_bads, file_goods, FILE_NAME_DATE_GOODS, FILE_NAME_DATE_BADS, good_list, bad_list

    for good in good_list:
        file_goods.write(good + '\n')
    file_goods.close()

    for bad in bad_list:
        file_bads.write(bad + '\n')
    file_bads.close()

    print('{} => Fully completed email scanning'.format(Fore.CYAN))
    print('{} => Good emails [{}] || Bad emails [{}]'.format(Fore.GREEN, FILE_NAME_DATE_GOODS, FILE_NAME_DATE_BADS))

def newChecker(email):
    global url, good_list, bad_list

    s = req.session()
    body = '{"Username":"%s"}' % email
    request = req.post(url, data=body)
    response = request.text
    valid = re.search('"IfExistsResult":0,', response)
    invalid = re.search('"IfExistsResult":1,', response)

    if invalid:
        bad_list.append(email)
    if valid:
        good_list.append(email)
    else:
        if valid:
            good_list.append(email)
        else:
            bad_list.append(email)


def mp_handler(p):
    global ALL_EMAILS
    p.map(newChecker, ALL_EMAILS)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Foreach email, parse it into our checker
    # Define a filename to save to
    FILE_NAME_DATE_GOODS = '{}{}{}'.format(location_emails_goods, todayString, '.txt')
    FILE_NAME_DATE_BADS = '{}{}{}'.format(location_emails_bads, todayString, '.txt')

    file_bads = open(FILE_NAME_DATE_BADS, 'a')
    file_goods = open(FILE_NAME_DATE_GOODS, 'a')

    p = multiprocessing.Pool(500)

    mp_handler(p)

    saveLogs()

    p.close()
```